# Does PHP come with UI components?

Tags: php, .net, user-interface, asp-classic, components

Mmmmmmh, I probably have the answer to this obious question myself, but I just want to hear someone else confirm this. Does PHP come with UI components?

I have used PHP before and am currently using ASP .NET. ASP .NET comes with UI components. Does this mean ASP .NET is better?

Comment: comparing a language with a framework isn't a good comparison: if you want UI components in PHP, take your pick of PHP-based frameworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a programming language with a web framework. There are a lot of well established PHP frameworks and most of them also provide some kind of view components.

Comment: Okay, so ASP .NET is a framework and PHP is only a language?

Comment: Yes, the comparison should be more like C#/F#/VB.NET to PHP

Comment: Technically, no web 'language' comes with 'controls'.  The controls are represented in the browser by the HTML mark-up you or your server side code supply, i.e. all you are doing is telling the browser what type of object you want and where to place it.  After that they are drawn by either the browser or and mix of the browser and operating system.  Exceptions to this, you could argue, are Silverlight, Flash and Applets.

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment: this is why everyone has so much ... *fun* with CSS, bless it!

Comment: Just use a CSS framework like Bootstrap if you don't want to loose some time with the UI and focus on the server side.